# Variational Auto Encoder produces the same picture as the input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to train a CVAE, convolutional variational auto encoder, to generate new pictures of human faces.

I'm using the same loss function, training step function, generating function etc. as in the official [TensorFlow CVAE Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cvae). I'll post them below.

The only thing I've changed is the encoder and decoder network and the input and output shapes (because I want 128x128 RGB pictures, while the tutorial deals with 28x28 MNIST pictures).

The problem I encounter is, that every picture generated (by `generate_and_save_images()`) is not a new one (variational), but just a picture that exists 1 by 1 in the dataset. (My training dataset has 518 pictures of faces)

So the generating of new pictures doesn't work, we just have the same pictures 1 by 1 recreated.

Why? And how to fix it?

```
  @tf.function
  def sample(self, eps=None):
    if eps is None:
      eps = tf.random.normal(shape=(100, self.latent_dim))
    return self.decode(eps, apply_sigmoid=True)

  def encode(self, x):
    mean, logvar = tf.split(self.encoder(x), num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)
    return mean, logvar

  def reparameterize(self, mean, logvar):
    eps = tf.random.normal(shape=mean.shape)
    return eps * tf.exp(logvar * .5) + mean

  def decode(self, z, apply_sigmoid=False):
    logits = self.decoder(z)
    if apply_sigmoid:
      probs = tf.sigmoid(logits)
      return probs
    return logits

def log_normal_pdf(sample, mean, logvar, raxis=1):
  log2pi = tf.math.log(2. * np.pi)
  return tf.reduce_sum(
      -.5 * ((sample - mean) ** 2. * tf.exp(-logvar) + logvar + log2pi),
      axis=raxis)

def compute_loss(model, x):
  mean, logvar = model.encode(x)
  z = model.reparameterize(mean, logvar)
  x_logit = model.decode(z)
  cross_ent = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=x_logit, labels=x)
  logpx_z = -tf.reduce_sum(cross_ent, axis=[1, 2, 3])
  logpz = log_normal_pdf(z, 0., 0.)
  logqz_x = log_normal_pdf(z, mean, logvar)
  return -tf.reduce_mean(logpx_z + logpz - logqz_x)

@tf.function
def train_step(model, x, optimizer):
  """Executes one training step and returns the loss.

  This function computes the loss and gradients, and uses the latter to
  update the model's parameters.
  """
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss = compute_loss(model, x)
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

# keeping the random vector constant for generation (prediction) so
# it will be easier to see the improvement.
random_vector_for_generation = tf.random.normal(
    shape=[num_examples_to_generate, latent_dim])

def generate_and_save_images(model, epoch, test_sample):
  mean, logvar = model.encode(test_sample)
  z = model.reparameterize(mean, logvar)
  predictions = model.sample(z)
  _ = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))

  for i in range(predictions.shape[0]):
    plt.subplot(4, 4, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(predictions[i, :, :, :])
    plt.axis('off')

  # tight_layout minimizes the overlap between 2 sub-plots
  plt.savefig(r'D:\...\image_at_epoch_{:04d}.png'.format(epoch))
  plt.show()
```

Comment: make the bottleneck tighter

Comment: Do you mean to reduce `latent_dim`?

Comment: My current is: `512`